# Qt, model-view-controller, простейший delegate

Tags: c++, qt, mvc

Сделал QTableView и производная от QAbstractTableModel.

В модели несколько столбцов - bool'ы.
Хочется редактировать их (переключать) кликом (или двойным кликом) по соответствующей ячейке.

Никак не соображу, как мне не создавать никаких editor'ов, а сразу в Delegate::createEditor() делать setModelData().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача, как выяснилось, имеет банальнейшее решение: `QTableView` (как `QAbstractItemView`, впрочем) имеет сигнал `clicked()`.

Далее всё просто:

```
public slot
void MyModel::itemClicked (const QModelIndex &index)
{
    // some magic
}

....

// в конструкторе всего этого безобразия
connect (ui->table, &QTableView::clicked, model, &MyModel::itemClicked);
```

Answer (score 2):

Суть делегата заключена в делегировании прав на редактирование данных модели отдельному виджету. Если используется делегат и поддерживается изменение ячейки, то соответствующий виджет-редактор должен быть создан обязательно.

В отдельных случаях, например, при использовании переключателей, это может показаться избыточным, однако зачастую важно предоставлять возможность отмены телодвижений пользователя с той целью, чтобы лишний раз не беспокоить модель беспорядочными щелчками по поводу и без.

Если задача сводится к тому, чтобы идти собственным путём, отличным от общепринятого, и менять значения в ячейках по событию щелчка, то вероятно лучше отказаться от использования делегатов вообще.

Переопределите в наследнике `QTableView` события мыши или подключитесь к сигналам `QItemSelectionModel`, которая доступна по `QAbstractItemView::selectionModel()`. И тогда, исходя из входных данных о ячейке, в которой был произведён щелчок мыши, меняйте соответствующие данные в модели.